# blue smoke from exhaust

Tags: vw

I have a VW crafter van 57 plate have had a lot of work done to it as it kept going into limp mode.by Bosch agents in Bristol !
My problem is when going down hill on over run @ the bottom of hill when depressing the throttle pedal I get a cloud of blue smoke from the exhaust, it is then clean the van goes ok. All so at times when @ traffic lights the engine rev's go up & a lot of smoke comes out of the exhaust, I switch off the engine & restart & every thing is fine. Any Ideas

Comment: How many miles? Turbo oil seals? Valve stem oil seals?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Agree with Mike here and wondering the same things. Seems like you've got oil being drawn into intake tract at times of high vacuum.

Comment: For those not in the UK, a 57 place means it's a 2007.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue on 07 plate 2.5l crafter after deaccelerating say like going down a hill, first touch of throttle after this would result in big puff of smoke but absolutely fine at all other times, it was the lambda sensor. changed this and it is now totally cured.only got this idea to change it from reading forums like this.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/65230)